# Is it possible to control disablelastaccess on a per disk basis in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I want to use Lastaccess info on the system disk at least for some time, but not on the storage disks.

1) Is it possible to control disablelastaccess on a per disk/partition basis in Windows 7?

2) Is this off by default on Windows 7 systems?  (it shows it here as DisableLastAccess = 1)

3) Is it a bad idea on Windows 7, for any reason other than slowing down the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know this setting is global to all discs. It is enabled by default meaning last access is NOT updated by default. I do not think it is a bad idea to disable it. You might also want to read [Find/sort files and folders based on when they were accessed/opened](https://superuser.com/questions/305226/find-sort-files-and-folders-based-on-when-they-were-accessed-opened/305260#305260)